# Casting buffer to function and executing in OS X

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm trying to run some assembly code saved in a buffer on OS X, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. The code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char buff[] = "\x66\x6a\7f\x66\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x66\x83\xec\x04\xcd\x80";
    ( void (*)()buff )(); /* same as calling return 127 */
    return 0;             /* program should never reach here */
}
```

The code in buff is generated by nasm and it works, it causes the program to return 127. When running through a c program like so though, I get a segmentation fault. Is there a different way to do this in OS X?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection

Comment: You ain't getting this running on OS X, I dare you.

Comment: For an ugly, ugly hack: declare your buffer as `static const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack is non executable by default -- you need to mark a page as executable with [`mprotect(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mprotect.2.html) in order to make it executable.  Making the stack executable is highly not recommended, so if you want to run code generated at runtime, you should allocate memory on the heap instead.

For example:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

// Error checking omitted for expository purposes

// Allocate 1 page of read-write memory
size_t page_size = getpagesize();
void *mem = mmap(NULL, page_size,
                 PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                 MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE,
                 -1, 0);
// Copy the shell code into the memory
char shellcode[] = "...";
memcpy(mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

// Change memory to executable and non-writable
mprotect(mem, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);

// Run the code
((void (*)())mem)();

// Free the memory
munmap(mem, page_size);
```

Comment: `buff` is not placed on the stack when optimization is enabled (`-O3`), in Apple clang 4.0.

Comment: It still segfaults, gdb says this:
`Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000001
0x0000000100053004 in ?? ()`
the code is just `"\x66\x55"` (push ebp) this time.

Comment: @ronmrdechai: After the `push ebp` gets executed, you need to do something else like return with a `ret` instruction—the CPU will keep reading code from memory, it doesn't just magically return to your code when it finishes executing `push ebp`.  But just a bare `ret` won't cut it, since now you've messed up the stack with your `push`.  You need to fix up the stack and then `ret`, or just `jump` or `call` out to a non-returning function (such as `exit`) if you want to avoid crashing.

Answer (score 3):

First, this will not compile, because you are missing the parentheses necessary to make `void (*)()` a cast. The line should be `((void (*)())buff)();`.

Second, if you compile without optimization, `buff` is likely constructed on the stack, and execution will fail because Mac OS X marks the stack as not executable.

Third, if you compile with optimization, `buff` is likely prepared in some data segment, and you may be able to execute it. But the instructions you have are inappropriate for the Mac OS X platform, and you get a normal access exception. You could step through the instructions in the debugger to figure out what is wrong.

The behavior of converting an object pointer to a function pointer and calling the function is not defined by the C standard. You should not rely on it to work.

Among the errors in the assembly code:

- It moves one to the `%ax` register, which is the low two bytes of the `%rax` register. This leaves the high six bytes uncontrolled. Then it attempts to use `%rax` as an address. This fails because the value in the `%rax` register is not pointing at accessible memory.
- It attempts to execute the instruction `int $0x80`. This is some Microsoft Windows, DOS, or Linux service call. On Mac OS X, it is an illegal instruction.

Comment: I pulled the code off of some OS X assembly example and tossed it into nasm without putting too much thought into it. It assembles, links, and runs fine though.